# You have 2 quarters. I need 1 quarter. Which quarter do I have?

Tags: lateral-thinking

Have asked several people and can't Google for help.

You have 2 quarters. I need 1 quarter. Which quarter do I have?

Comment: You already have three quarters and you need 1 quarter to make a whole???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ummm...

> **Neither of them**?
>  Because both of them are yours, not mine.